# GitHub action completed successfully but Docker containers not available

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I have a GitHub action CI CD that checks out code and runs docker-compose.yml. In the log, I can see it starting both the containers but when I ssh into the system and do a docker ps, do not see any containers.

Here is my GitHub action -

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout files
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
  
  deploy:
    needs: build_and_push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout files
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
    - name: Deploy to Digital Ocean droplet via SSH action
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.3
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
    
    - name: Start containers
      run: docker-compose up -d --build
    
    - name: Dump docker logs
      uses: jwalton/gh-docker-logs@v1
```

Please suggest how should I troubleshoot this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`appleboy/ssh-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) actions explains how to run commands on the remote server: By using the `script` attribute.

In your case:

```yaml
jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout files
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
  
  deploy:
    needs: build_and_push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout files
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
    - name: Deploy to Digital Ocean droplet via SSH action
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.3
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script: |                            <=====
          docker-compose up -d --build       <=====
    
    - name: Dump docker logs
      uses: jwalton/gh-docker-logs@v1
```